# How to for-each loop using 3 array

Tags: php

```
 $sociallinkflied1 = $row['sociallinkflied'];
 $codes = explode(',', $sociallinkflied1);
 $sociallinktitle = $row['sociallink'];
 $names = explode(',', $sociallinktitle);
 $sociallinkflied = $row['sociallinkflied'];
 $sociallinkflied1 = explode(',', $sociallinkflied);

foreach( $codes as $index => $code ){
   echo '<a href='.$names[$index].' target=" '._blank.'" style="margin: 10px;">
 <i class="fa '.$code.'"></i>'.$sociallinkflied1[$index].'
 </a>';
                                               }
```

How To used this 3 array in for each loop.please help me solve this issue

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not clear what your question is, or what specific problem you've had using the arrays i the loop. Also, please only tag appropriately. Your question has nothing to do with [tag:javascript] and isn't really about [tag:html] either, it's just about [tag:php]. Tagging indiscriminately will not improve your chances of getting good answers or having well-received questions; quite the reverse.

Comment: When you reference the `$sociallinkflied1` array, you use `$inbox` as the index and not `$index`.

Comment: `$inbox` ?? Where does this come from?

Comment: Code seems to be fine if you change `$inbox` to `$index`. So what's the problem you are facing now?

Comment: @Alive in what sense is the code "fine"? Even after fixing the `$inbox` error, the code has multiple issues. And the OP has already stated their problem: How to use 3 arrays in a foreach loop.

Comment: 1.I always prefer `foreach()` over `for()` [as it take care of indexes itself.]

2.The main problem in your code is quotes issue not logic issue (and it's not mentioned by other ansmwer)

Check below code:-

`foreach( $codes as $index => $code ){
 echo '<a href="'.$names[$index].'" target="_blank" style="margin: 10px;"><i class="fa '.$code.'"></i>'.$sociallinkflied1[$index].'</a>';
 echo "\n";
}`
Output:- https://eval.in/1058773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking how to loop over multiple arrays at the same time in PHP. You are correct in thinking you need to refer to the array items by index.

But you need to use a `for` loop because the index is a number. And you must refer to **all** of the arrays by index:

```
$names = array("Tom", "Dick", "Harry");
$codes = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
$links = array("/foo", "/bar", "/qux");

$number_of_items = count($names); # could use any of the arrays, if they are all the same size

for ($index = 0; $index < $number_of_items; $index++) {
   echo '<a href="'.$links[$index].'">
    <i class="fa '.$codes[$index].'"></i>'.$names[$index].'
</a>';
    echo "\n";
}
```

Good luck with your program!

Comment: Thanks...Will Sheppard